# How to compare 2 pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-9

I'm training with many to many relationships and today i'm trying to compare 2 pivot tables.

I'm trying a site for a nutritionist.
On one hand the nutritionist/admin can create patient's card (my table "User". In this cards he informs the regime's type of this patient. It's a many to many relationship so i made a "regime_user" table pivot.

```
Schema::create('regime_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('regime_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

On the other hand he can create receipts (my table is "Recette") and informs regime's type. Again i use a pivot table "recette_regime".

```
Schema::create('recette_regime', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('recette_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('regime_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Of course in my Models i've added the relation:
For the User Model :

```
public function regimes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Regime::class);
}
```

For the Regime Model :

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

What i want to do now in the receipts's index is to display for the auth()->user() only the receipts who has the same regime's types. So i need to compare the 2 pivots table :

- which regime's types has the auth()->user()
- find the receipts which have the same regime's types

I've read the doc and find nothing i could use. Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi @Karl, welcome to stack, please post your models (the part of the relationships), you may edit your original post with the extra data, and I will show you to do it using standard practices.

Comment: Hello KGG, i add my models relation :)

Comment: please check the answer below, if there is an issue with Recette model, please include it in the main post. Also if you need further explanation and clarifications, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of data you have inside of `"Regime & Recette"` but I will assume in this example that the column `name` exists, to show the concept of how you can present the data.

**User Model:**

```
public function regimes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Regime::class);
}
```

**Regime Model:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function recettes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Recette::class);
}
```

**Recette Model:**

```
public function regimes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Regime::class);
}
```

**In UserController show function:**

```
/**
 * Show the specified model.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  User $user
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(User $user){
    // This will lazy load all of the inner relationships:
    $user->load('regimes.recettes');
   
    // Return the view with the user
    return view('sampleView', compact('user')); 
}
```

**In sampleView Blade:**

```
<!-- You call the regime relationship and display it !-->
@foreach($user->regimes as $regime)
    <ul>
        <li>ID: {{$regime->id}} - Name: {{$regime->name}}
            <ul>
                <!-- You call the recette relationship and display it !-->
                @forelse($regime->recettes as $recette)
                    <li>ID: {{$recette->id}} - Name: {{$recette->name}}</li>
                @empty
                    <li>No Data</li>
                @endforelse
            </ul>
        </li>       
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I can try that but in fact this is not a show function i need, it's the index of the recette page. When a guest or an auth will connect to the site he will be on the recette index, and on this page the guest will see all the recettes, the auth will see only the recette with their regime type. So i can't pass $user in the function :/

Comment: In fact i used the same idea than you, i was focused on my first idea. Instead of $user was the auth()->user()->id and it works. Thank you !

Comment: I'm really happy that it worked out for you @Karl if you have any future questions, please dont hesitate to ask, if you liked the answer, kindly consider leaving an upvote on my answer, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer i'm not sure it worked. Ty for your kindness ^^
Btw yesterday i asked another question on the same theme, maybe you have the answer too ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using `whereHas()`

```
$user = auth()->user();

$receipts = Recette::whereHas('regimes', function($query) use($user) {
    $query->whereIn('regime_id', $user->regimes->pluck('id'));
})->get();
```

Comment: I tried and it works too. Ty i keep it for the next time :)